# How to get the number of the highlighted row in QTableWidget?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtablewidget, pyqt6

In pyqt6 how do I get the row that is highlighted in the QTableWidget when I move the arrow keys?

[image]

The `tableWidget.currentRow()` command only returns the row when I click on it.

Comment: use `tableWidget.selectedItems()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `QTableWidget().itemSelectionChanged.connect()` to easily retrieve the selection with arrow keys.
https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtablewidget.html
I use PySide2, but I think it should be the same with pyqt6.
My example :

```py
import sys
from functools import partial
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
import random 
import string

_datas = []
for i in range(10): 
    nmb = f"{random.randrange(123, 9999)}".zfill(6)
    text = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for j in range(5))
    _datas.append((nmb, text))

class MY_APP(QMainWindow) :
    def __init__(self, ):
        super().__init__()
        self.create_ui()
        self.setup_connection()

    def create_ui(self):
        self.resize(QSize(500, 600))
        central_wid = QWidget()
        
        self.setCentralWidget(central_wid)

        central_wid.setLayout(QHBoxLayout())
        self.my_table = QTableWidget()
        self.my_table.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.my_table.setSelectionMode(QTableWidget.ExtendedSelection)
        self.my_table.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.my_table.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.my_table.setColumnCount(2)
        for row, _d in enumerate(_datas) : 
            self.my_table.insertRow(row)
            for col, col_value in enumerate(_d) : 
                item = QTableWidgetItem()
                item.setText(col_value)
                self.my_table.setItem(row, col, item)

        central_wid.layout().addWidget(self.my_table)

        self.reportView = QPlainTextEdit()
        central_wid.layout().addWidget(self.reportView)


    def setup_connection(self): 
        # connected function to item selection changed trigger of my_table
        self.my_table.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.action_report_in_view)

    def action_report_in_view(self, *arg):
        values = []
        for selected_item in self.my_table.selectedItems():
            # create [item from col 0, item from col 1]
            values.insert(selected_item.column(), selected_item.text())
        self.add_to_log(values)

    def add_to_log(self, value):
        self.reportView.appendPlainText(str(value))
        
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MY_APP()
window.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]